# mail not getting sent on server

Tags: php

I have 2 websites on hosted but on one web site I can send mail using php script using other web site I cannot mail using the php script. I don't know where I am going wrong. I even replaced php.ini file. Is there any other thing which I left doing or something.

This is my code

```
$to="abc@gmail.com";
$subject="test mail";
$body="test mail";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n"; 
$headers.='From: Domain <def@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";


if(mail($to,$subject,$body,$header)) 
{
echo "mailed";
}
else
{
echo "not mailed";
}
```

I even tried directly embedding message into the mail function that also doesn't seems to be working.

This is the code after embedding message

```
if(mail("abc@gmail.com", "Test subject", "Test Message", "From: def@gmail.com"))
        {
            echo "mailed";
        }
        else
        {
        echo "error:".mysql_error();
        }
```

I tried contacting my hosting providers technical people. Even they could not find the solution.

Comment: So are you getting an error with `mysql_error()` or you get `mailed`, but it actually never reaches the target's inbox? Also, I do not think `abc` and `def` are exact recipients and you replace them with some valid emails. Thus, maybe you are trying to send an email from the domain wich has a different domain than the email? If so, try changing them to be the same. What about the spam boxes too?

Comment: I'm getting not mailed for above program and for second program I'm just getting error: I think php errors are not enabled on my server and in php.ini file I tried I could'nt enable it

Comment: Is your php even working in it? Because if you cannot send mails, cannot get errors... what comes to mind: does anything work?

Comment: yes when i echo something it shows me on my browser that means php script is working fine rt ? and phpinfo also shows me all other components

Answer (score 0):

it's Sample And Works for me:

```
        $to ='Info@sample.com';
        $message = '<a>Hellow</a>';
        $subject ='Hello world';
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: <sender@email.com>" . "\r\n";
$mail_sent=@mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo $mail_sent ? "Success" : "Error";
```

if this code not working , Call to Your server Administrator For check Server...

Comment: It is working with godaddy hosting on one web site and not working on other web site and I tried contacting godaddy technical people it does'nt seems to work with their solution